# Deleting Duplicates with VBA Based on Two Columns- Excel 2003

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using Excel 2003 having the following table and want to remove the duplicate rows based on first name and last name if they are the same.

```
-------------------------------------
| first name | last name | balance  | 
-------------------------------------
| Alex       | Joe       | 200      |
| Alex       | Joe       | 200      |
| Dan        | Jac       | 500      |
-------------------------------------
```

so far i have a VB macro that only remove duplicates if the first name is duplicate.

```
    Sub DeleteDups() 

    Dim x               As Long 
    Dim LastRow         As Long 

    LastRow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row 
    For x = LastRow To 1 Step -1 
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A1:A" & x), Range("A" & x).Text) > 1 Then 
            Range("A" & x).EntireRow.Delete 
        End If 
    Next x 

End Sub
```

and please advice if it is possible to run this macro once the file opened.thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're working with Excel 2003, `.RemoveDuplicates` and `COUNTIFs` not supported, so you can try this one:

```
Sub DeleteDups()

    Dim x As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngToDel As Range
    'change sheet1 to suit
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For x = LastRow To 2 Step -1
            If Evaluate("=ISNUMBER(MATCH('" & .Name & "'!A" & x & " & '" & .Name & "'!B" & x & ",'" & .Name & "'!A1:A" & x - 1 & " & '" & .Name & "'!B1:B" & x - 1 & ",0))") Then
                If rngToDel Is Nothing Then
                    Set rngToDel = .Range("A" & x)
                Else
                    Set rngToDel = Union(rngToDel, .Range("A" & x))
                End If
            End If
        Next x
    End With

    If Not rngToDel Is Nothing Then rngToDel.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

this solution based on the formula `=ISNUMBER(MATCH(A100 & B100 ,A1:A99 & B1:B99, 0))` with array entry, which returns `TRUE` if there're duplicates in rows above and `FALSE` othervise.

To run this macro just after opening workbook, add next code to `ThisWorkbook` module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Call DeleteDups

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use a dictionary to store the values. Any value already existing in the dictionary can be deleted during the iteration as well.

### **Code:**

```
Sub RemoveDuplicates()

    Dim NameDict As Object
    Dim RngFirst As Range, CellFirst As Range
    Dim FName As String, LName As String, FullName As String
    Dim LRow As Long

    Set NameDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    With Sheet1 'Modify as necessary.
        LRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set RngFirst = .Range("A2:A" & LRow)
    End With

    With NameDict
        For Each CellFirst In RngFirst
            With CellFirst
                FName = .Value
                LName = .Offset(0, 1).Value
                FullName = FName & LName
            End With
            If Not .Exists(FullName) And Len(FullName) > 0 Then
                .Add FullName, Empty
            Else
                CellFirst.EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

### **Screenshots:**

**Before running:**

[image]

**After running:**

[image]

You can call this from a `Workbook_Open` event to trigger it every time you open the workbook as well.

Let us know if this helps.

Comment: I was just working with your code to do a very large list with over 300 duplicates and it was missing some of them.  I think instead of starting at the top you need to start from the bottom and work your way up.

Comment: Deleting rows always has issues. Starting from the bottom may work properly. Another approach to this is not to delete during the iteration but use `Union` to combine the rows that fullfill the `Else` condition. Then delete them altogether at the end.

Answer (score 1):

It works in excel 2007.  Try in 2003 may be it'll help you

```
Sub DeleteDups() 

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2", Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count, 3)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlNo

End Sub
```